# Не подключается script в footer wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Не могу найти ошибку. Делаю по инструкции, но скрипт не подключается в футер.

Вот такой код в functions.php

```html
function roof_scripts() { 
   // js так работает, но подключается в хедер, а надо в футер
   wp_enqueue_script( 
    'scripts', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js'
   ); 

   // js не работает 
   wp_enqueue_script( 
    'scripts', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js',
    array(),
    '1.0.0',
    true
   );

} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'roof_scripts' );
```

Вот такой хедер и футер

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <!-- не важный код-->
    <?php wp_head()?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class()?>>
    <!-- не важный код-->
```

```html
    <!--Не важный код-->
</body>
<?php wp_head()?>
</html>
```

Вот так выглядит страница:

```html
<?php get_header();?>
<!--Контент-->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: а где вызов `wp_footer();`?

Comment: Я исправил вопрос, добавил как выглядит страница. Я использовал  get_footer а не wp_footer из-за этого может быть ошибка?

Comment: Написал ответ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вижу вызова `wp_footer();`. Без выполнения этого вызова footer не сформируется, и никакие скрипты в него не попадут. Потому что:

1. Эта функция вызывает акцию 'wp_footer'
2. Эта акция по умолчанию вызывает `_wp_footer_scripts()`
3. Эта функция вызывает `print_footer_scripts()`

Ваш вызов `get_footer()` делает несколько иное - подтягивает шаблон footer.php, если он есть. А вот footer.php в темах заканчивают обычно так:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как раз в этом и была проблема